# Changing attribute rendered or visible in primefaces via checkbox

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsf, checkbox, primefaces

How can I change the attribute rendered/ visible to true which is initially set to false when I click on a checkbox ?

```
<p:selectBooleanCheckbox itemLabel = "Show">
   <p:ajax execute = "age" render = "true"/>
</p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
```

What I want to achieve is that upon check of the checkbox, an additional column is generated (ajax) to display the Age records.

```
<p:column headerText="Age" visible= "false" id = "age">
        <h:outputText value="#{stud.age}" />
</p:column>
```

Any idea how can I achieve this in primefaces or using javascript? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the value of the checkbox in a backing bean and use that for the decision of the age column should be rendered. Here is a simple, but working example:

xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head />
<h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{test.show}" itemLabel="Show" >
                <p:ajax update="table"/>
            </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <p:dataTable id="table">
                <p:column headerText="Name"></p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Age" rendered="#{test.show}"></p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

The backing bean:

```
@Named("test")
@ViewScoped
public class TestBean {

    private boolean show;

    public boolean isShow() {
        return show;
    }

    public void setShow(boolean show) {
        this.show = show;
    }
}
```

Note: this one rerenders the whole datatable, which might be slow with a lot of data.

Comment: How can I get one which renders only the column?

Comment: I think it would only possible, if you would render the Age column as well, but it would be initially hidden. My solution needs a full rerender of the datatable, because it needs to fetch the column values from the bean for each row, since those values are not included in the initial version of the table.